# Thread Usage and drawing issues under non-debug mode

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, drawing, visual-studio-debugging

I am using Visual Studio 2012, writing in c#. My program has an acquisition thread that runs in the background. It goes something like this:

Inside the thread:

```
public void myAcquisitionTask(object o)
{
    while(ThreadAlive)
    {
        // Collect data
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

And called:

```
Thread myThread;
myThread.start(data);
```

In my GUI, I have a clickable button that draws some data (as a `Graphics` object) when clicked. It is basically some lines, but there are a lot of lines (around 50000). The drawing is done like:

```
private void btnDisplaySavedData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graphicsObj = myDisplay.CreateGraphics();

    // Do for multiple lines
    graphicsObj.DrawLine(pen, startpt, endpt);

    graphicsObj.Dispose();
}
```

I realised that while the thread is running, the `Graphics` object will draw; but just as the drawing is completed, it will be `erased`.

Interestingly, this behaviour occurs only in non-debug mode (ctrl-f5 in Visual Studio), and never in debug mode. In addition, I realised that if I do not call `myThread.start()` in non-debug mode, the drawing works as well.

This leads me to believe that there is a relationship between the thread and the drawing. Does anyone know what could be the possible cause?

Comment: Please clarify what is `myThread` .

Comment: `myThread` is the instance of an object for the `Thread` class. I have edited my question for clarity.

Comment: Can you post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? So that we can see the same problem you're see.

Comment: I assume based on your mention of `Graphics` this is Winforms. The _only_ correct way to draw in Winforms is to handle the `Paint` event (with a handler or override `OnPaint()` in a subclass), and to draw based on some current state of your data. You haven't provided a sufficient code example, but it is a likely guess that you are not doing this, but instead just do something like calling `CreateGraphics()` and draw when the button is clicked. That it works at all in debug mode is just a happy coincidence. It could easily fail there too.

Comment: Yep. turns out that not drawing in OnPaint() caused the issue.